# Linking two Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have one single file component that is used to show data and another one that is used to edit the same data. The view has labels and paragraphs where as the edit component has inputs and textareas.

Both of these components take the same data object. Is there a way that by editing the fields (bound with `v-model` in the edit component) the changes a reflected to the view component?

For example, here's my `paragraph.vue` that is used to show the data

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>{{ text }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and here's the edit dialog

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paragaph-text">Paragraph</label>
        <textarea id="paragaph-text" class="form-control" v-model.trim="text"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: if they have same parent component then you can use event to signal new paragraph value.

Comment: If you want use events then read about Component props https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props  and about custom events https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events
 in official documentation. I guess that solution presented there is one you are looking for. Of course centralized state management (with vuex) is really good solution too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple components using the same data, you can use a share state as explained in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch).

But if the number of components increases, and there are many changes happening, you may need a Centralized State Management like [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex), which is generally preferred in due community.