# One global data structure in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am building a single page app with Vue.js. It's a relatively simple app, more like an extended, opinionated spreadsheet. I'm using `vue-router` to handle different views of the app, some are used to enter new data, some are used to perform calculations on the data but all that data is intertwined (data entered in view #1 is used to enter data in view #2 and then both are used to calculate something in view #3).

That means I need a global data structure. From my research I found that I have several options to handle that:

- the "proper" way: emitting events in components and handling them in the parent; that seems a little overcomplicated for what I want to achieve
- accessing the parent scope directly in component templates via `$parent.$data`
- my current solution, assigning the parent data reference to the child data object

Like so:

```
const REPORTS = {
  template: templates.reports,
  data: function(){
    return this.$parent.$data
  }
};
```

However, my sixth sense is telling me that it's not a good practice.

If I'm right, **what are better ways of achieving this: one, global data structure, accessible from all components?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [central state management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) as docs says:

> Large applications can often grow in complexity, due to multiple pieces of state scattered across many components and the interactions between them. To solve this problem, Vue offers [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex): our own Elm-inspired state management library. It even integrates into vue-devtools, providing zero-setup access to time travel.

You can have a look at my other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955110/1610034) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910358/1610034)

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) [state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) can be read via [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html), updated synchronously using [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html), updated asynchronously via [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) from all the vue components and even divided into different [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, how bad is passing the parent data reference to children?

Comment: @angr Not bad at all, if communication is limited to parent child, you can always go for parent child communication as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40915910/1610034), but if you need to communicate between multiple component which can become messy later than use vuex.