# Vus.js 2.0 Laravel 5.4 pass object to app and use it globally accross components

Tags: javascript, laravel, global-variables, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to load the authenticated user and use it accross all my vue components (without an unnecessary ajax request since I can load it directly from the back-end).

My Laravel `home.blade.php` references a `Vue` app and I tried binding the `Auth::user()` to the main vue:

```
<div id="app" :authuser="{{ Auth::user() ? : '[]' }}"></div>
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: ['authuser'],
  data: { authuser: this.authuser }
});
```

But it seems you cannot pass props to the main `Vue` object. What is the best way to do it?

**Note:** I am open to other suggestions than passing through props. Ideally, I would like to reference an `authuser` object globally from all my vue components. Maybe through `window.authuser` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to the blade template before calling `app.js` does the trick:

```
<script>
  let authuser = {!! Auth::user() ? : '[]' !!};
</script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This will allow you to use `authuser` directly and globally in any component, for example:

```
<template>
  <div class="answer" v-if="authUserAnswered">
     Edit Answer
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['answer'],
    computed: {
      authUserAnswered() { return authuser.id == this.answer.user_id; }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is cleaner than using `this.$root` every time.

You can learn more about [Shared States here](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/24).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this can be using [$root](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root). As suggested [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/1652/how-to-use-a-global-data-object-with-vue-router-that-gets-shared-with-components/2), you should be able to set in the `app` component and use it across components.

In your **app.js**:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created () {
    // will fire the first time the router is loaded,
    // and won't be called again until page refresh
    // maybe load in your data dynamically?
    this.$root.authuser = this.authuser;
  }
});
```

And then in your component:

```
this.$root.authuser
```

---

Other way to do this can be using a [central state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) or [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) which is more popular among the community.  You can have a look at similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41319135/1610034). You can commit to vuex [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) in the `created`/`mounted` block of **app.js** and later can access it in any components with help of [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).

Comment: In your example, how do you get the `this.authuser` from php into `const app`?

Comment: @BassemLhm [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/pass-data-from-view-to-vue-instance?page=1) should help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer combined with a laracast I watched made me find my answer. I wanted to avoid the repetition of this.$root.authuser all over my components.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js, you can declare global variables.

For example:

```
// app.js
global.user = 'hello';

// anywhere else, you can access the user var
console.log(user);
```

You can also apply this to the vue object itself(if you want):

```
global.vm = new Vue({
    methods: {
        helloWorld(){}
    }
});
```

And you'll be able to access it's methods and so on from other components: `vm.helloWorld();`.

To get user into app.js, you may print it in JSON between script tags. Your app.js should be able to access it later. eg.

```
<script>
    var user="{{$user}}";
</script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But maybe it would be better to use an AJAX request.