# How to pass computed property from component somewhere else

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have working example from official site.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xkkbfL3L/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xkkbfL3L)

```
 computed: { filteredData: function () {} )
```

How to get filteredData (computed property) globally? Espiccially if I want to send it somewhere else. demo.$store contains only original properties, not computed. I see the only way to achieve this is demo.$children[0].filteredData. But that is not pure. By the way, im using vuex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One global data structure in Vue.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318800/one-global-data-structure-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed data is only available to the current component. However you can use [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) in Vuex and import that as computed property where ever is needed.

In vuex, you declare this:

```
getters: {
  filteredData (state) {
    return state.data.filter(x => x)
  }
}
```

and then, where you require it, you just imported:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      filteredData
    })
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but dissapointed of this. Would be great if computed were placed in Vuex.store

Comment: But properties (data, computed, props) are component specific. If you need to compute things in vuex, you can use getters for that.

Comment: Would it be possible to use an EventBus instead of vuex for this?