# Can't access root data in VueJS

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

It's my first post on stackoverflow, so sorry in advance if I do something incorrectly. My question;

I've setup a VueJS project, and I'm trying to reach data that I put in the App.vue from another component. To do this, I use this.$root.count for example, but it returns undefined.

**Main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: function (resolve) {
        require(['./components/Hello.vue'], resolve)
    }
}, {
    path: '/race-pilot',
    name: 'racePilot',
    component: function (resolve) {
        require(['./components/RacePilot.vue'], resolve)
    }
}
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
});
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="menu" ref="menu">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'racePilot' }">Race Pilot</router-link>
    </div>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<style src="./assets/css/app.scss" lang="scss"></style>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        Hello
    },
    data () {
        return {
            count: '0'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**RacePilot.vue:**

```
<template>
<div class="race-pilot">
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'RacePilot',
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.$root.count);
    }
}
</script>
```

So the last log returns undefined. However, if I log this.$root, I do get the object. Anybody any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuex is fine and all, but if you just want to expose a property to all of your views in a router based app, you can set it on the router-view.

```
<router-view :count="count"></router-view>
```

Then your view component just needs to accept it as a prop.

```
export default {
    props:["count"],
    name: 'RacePilot',
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only question I would have; what if I'm in a really deep component, three childs away, and want to change the global variable count? Since this.$root doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Several options. Use Vuex would be what a lot of people would tell you, but I find Vuex to be overkill for small projects. Event bus would be the easiest. Or you could invent your own Vuex-like store that is available to all components using a global mixin.

Comment: Here's an example of a super simple store for global data http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XMqvPo?editors=1010

Comment: @BertEvans Nice and clean answer, what's the best way to provide async data (from a server), like user data?

Comment: @Sandrooco your properties can be async data. When they change, children will receive the updated properties.

Answer (score 3):

this.$root references the top level Vue instance (new Vue...) and **not** the App VueComponent.

it is really hacky, other solutions are preferable, but this could work:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App },
    methods: {
      getCount() {
        return this.$children[0].count
      }
    },
});
```

and using getCount() in RacePilot.vue:

```
export default {
    name: 'RacePilot',
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.$root.getCount());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access data which is stored in `App.vue` but this data will be local to the component and not accessible globally.

`App.vue` is not the root instance (referred to by `$root`), instead it is the first component within the root instance which is actually created at `main.js`. It is during this creation time, you need to pass the data which will then be exposed for all child components via `$root`.

Here is the relevant portion of `main.js`, modified accordingly :-

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { count: 0 },
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
});
```

Tip : To confirm that `App.vue` is indeed the first child of root instance, try comparing the references of `this.$root` with `this.$parent`. It should return`true` which means that root instance is the parent of `App.vue`.

References :-

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it like that.

Definitely you should not try to access other components like that.

To share data between components you can either use props (one-way binding) or Vuex to make data accessible and editable from all components through store.

You can use global `$store` or `$router` if you will start your Vue app this way:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    router,
    store
    render: h => h(require('./App'))
  })
```

Then you can access store (for state change or access state (do not mutate state this way)) - `this.$store.state.yourStaneName`

Comment: I do understand that, however, what if I need a global variable in the root (app.vue). For example a state change, or general data?

Comment: Edited answer to give you more explanation what you can use as global in your app.

Comment: Ah thanks, haven't worked with VueX yet. I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

It should had worked as it is, as it is working [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aednwnfy/1/).

However a better way to manage global variables, which are available across components should be solved by state machine. Vue has [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) for that purpose as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910358/1610034).

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the `App` component the actual root by passing the component directly to the Vue instance, which would look something like this:

```
new Vue(App).$mount('#app')
```

You'll probably have to move the router to `App.vue`, but this will make sure that `this.$root` will resolve to your `App` component directly.