# Vuejs - cannot access $root data from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue.js to manage the user and I have this piece of code to initialize vue:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',
    i18n: i18n,
    data:{ store },
    router: router,
    created()
    {
      this.store.user.actions.getUser();
    }
});
```

Inside `store` I have:

```
const store =
{
  user:
  {
    state:
    {
      user: null
    },
    actions:
    {
      getUser()
      {
        //method to retrieve user usign axios
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, the user is correctly initialized.

Now, I have also a vue component with the following:

```
computed:
{
  getUser()
  {
    console.log(this.$root.store.user.state.user)
  }
},
methods:
{
  init()
  {
    console.log(this.$root.store.user.state.user)
  }
},
created()
{
  this.init();
}
```

But the `console.log(this.$root.store.user.state.user)`  inside the `init()` method results in `null`, while the one inside `computed` returns the actual user.

Why it's like this? Shouldn't the `init()` method returns the user anyway?

Thank you all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978826/cant-access-root-data-in-vuejs

Comment: Have you tried renaming `store` to `myStore` ?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Thank you: I have already seen that question, but in my case I would prefer not to use props, since the component I was talking about in the question is a page called up via vue-router

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes, I have already tried to rename `store`, but unfortunately the `init()` method always returns `null`

Comment: Actually, the `init()` is returning the user, but it does so before the axios request has been resolved. You should use computed getters instead.

Comment: @IgorMoraru Thanks Igor, this is what I feared: the problem of using cumputed getters is that the value is not always initialized when the component is created and consequently there are cases in which this value is not shown immediately on the page template. Is there a way to get `user` to be captured before the page is mounted (since `mounted()` returns `null`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to change your `init()` method to return Promise - then you can wait for that Promise to resolve before instantiating the whole Vue application:

```js
store.init().then(() =>
{
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#dashboard',
    i18n: i18n,
    data:{ store },
    router: router,
    created()
    {
      this.store.user.actions.getUser();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @IVOGELOV, that's exactly what I did to solve my problem!